# Shortcut to apply same rule to all inputs in COdeigniter form validation?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have large forms on my website, and they all need to be validated on submission. Since I am working in codeigniter, I usually set form validation rules for each input manually like this :

```
$validation_rules = array ( 
    array ( 'field' => 'name', 'label' => 'Full name', 'rules' => 'required' ), 
    array ( 'field' => 'telephone', 'label' => 'Contact Number', 'rules' => 'required' ),
    ---
    ---
    ---
);
```

1. Since all the fields going to have same rule **(required)** and a
   single error message **'All the fields are required'**, so I was
   wondering is there a way to not write same line of code for each
   input ?
2. Also, since there will only be one message so how do I make the
   input left black turn to red outline after refresh ?

---

**Looks like a loop could do  for the first problem?**

```
foreach ( $this->input->post (  ) as $key => $value )
    {

        if ( strcasecmp ( $key, 'email' ) === 0 )
        {

            $this->form_validation->set_rules ( $key, ucfirst ( $key ), 'required|valid_email|trim' );

        }
        else
        {

            $this->form_validation->set_rules($key, ucfirst($key), 'required|trim');

        }

    }
```